# setTimeout only runs once

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add a delay to the `cleatRect` function, my aim is to make the animated sprites create a 'trailing effect' However, the `setTimeout` function only runs once when the canvas animation starts.
Am I missing something obvious?

```
var draw = function() { // draw loop 
    setTimeout(function() { // this runs once
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 560);
    }, 2000);

    ctx.drawImage(sprites.background, bkg.x, bkg.y);
    aliens.forEach(function(element, index) {
        ctx.drawImage(sprites.enemy, element.clipX, element.clipY, element.w, element.h, element.x, element.y, element.w, element.h);
    });
};
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't strictly need to wrap a function passed to `setTimeout` in an anonymous function if all you want to do is supply parameters: if you call `setTimeout/setInterval` with more than two arguments, all extras will be passed to your function like this `setTimeout(alert, 1000, "hello")`. Do be careful with the `this` context which might get changed, though.

Comment: To create a trailing FX dont clear the canvas at the start of each main loop. Draw the background image with ctx.globalAlpha < 1 this will have the effect of leaving a trail. This will work for alpha values > 0.05 but lower (and longer trails) values will add artifacts. If you wish longer trails you can draw the background every other or more frames.

Answer (score 2):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

> Sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.

You want: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. Returns an intervalID.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried

setInterval(function() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 560);
}, 2000);

no luck here either